# how to understand \n in vim

Tags: vim

I have a text file with following content:

```
elephant

rhino

giraffe

/* animals who live in Africa */
```

I would like to add `#` character at the end of each animal. I can do this with `:%s/\n\n/#\r\r/g` in vim. However, at first I tried with `:%s/\n\n/#\n\n/g` and I ended up with:

```
elephant#^@^@rhino#^@^@giraffe#^@^@/* animals who live in Africa */
```

Why does vim behave like that? How to understand `\n` in vim?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim

Comment: You can also do it like this: `:%s/\ze\n\n/#/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the replacement side of vim substitution, a newline is represented by `\r`.  Thus, try:

```
%s/\n\n/#\r\r/g
```

The resulting file will look like:

```
elephant#

rhino# 

giraffe#

/* animals who live in Africa */
```

In the first half of a substitute command, `\n` is a newline and `\r` is a carriage return.  By contrast, in the replacement side of the command, `\n` is a NUL character (hex 00) and `\r` is a newline.

Comment: This is the result of an internal storage convention, see `:h NL-used-for-Nul` and `:h CR-used-for-NL`.  It applies to a number of things, f.i. `s/.../.../` and `readfile()`, but not all.  Confusingly, you have to use `\n`, not `\r`, in the replacement string in `substitute()`.  Proof: `:echo substitute('abc', 'b', "\n", '')`.